# nslookup error: connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Tags: dns, vpn, ipconfig

My Ubuntu is 20.04.6. Recently, I installed VPN, then I found I cannot connect to the Internet (even after I uninstalling it). I have tried all the methods, but with no luck. Following are commands:

1. nslookup

   connection timed out; no servers could be reached
2. ping website return

   Temporary failure in name resolution

   (ping ip address ok)
3. cat /etc/resolv.conf

   nameserver 127.0.0.53
4. ll /etc/network (no interface file)

   [image]
5. ifconfig

   [image]
6. ip link show

   [image]
7. ip route

   [image]
8. route
   [image]

Any comment is really appreciated!